# Enable click functionality in jquery ui draggable's header

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

**Libraries used: jquery.blockUI.js,jquery-ui.css,jquery-ui.min.js .**

This is a very old maintainence project using jquery and blockui.

I am using blockui for pop up. Recently I implemented dragable feature 
..

```
$.blockUI(

 {
    message: $('#MyPopUpDiv'),
    theme: true,//Make the pop up draggable
    draggable: true,
    fadeIn: 300,
    fadeOut: 300,
    showOverlay: true,
    centerY: 0

 }
);
```

..
I had a header in my div previously, with a close button (image). 
Now I used jquery to copy the header div into the dragable header.

..

```
/* Get jquery generated header element */

var headerdiv = $('.ui-widget-header');

/* My previous header with close button */

    <div id="divHeaderWithCloseButton">
        <span style="float:left">Please click on cross button to close</span>

        <span class="closeme" style="float: right">
        <img alt="#" src="../../images/close2.jpg">         
    </span>
</div>


 /* Get my previous header div's markup so that I can add my div to header provided by jquery ui */

var appendHdrContent = $("#divHeaderWithCloseButton").html();


/* Remove My previous header div from existing DOM */

$("#divHeaderWithCloseButton").remove();


/* Append my div into header provided by jquery */

headerdiv.html(appendHdrContent);
```

..

So far so good.

However something is making click event on the image disabled. I want to fire jquery function when user clicks on the image inside the header.

Also I tried this but with no success

..

```
$('.closeme').click(function(){

    /*Nothing is getting fired :( */
    alert('Close button is clicked');

    //blockui code to close the pop 
    -----
    -----
});
```

/*This too Not working*/

headerdiv.removeClass('noclick');
..

How can I enable click within the header area of jquery provided draggable

Comment: Do you add the click listener before or after you set the headerdiv html? If you do it before, I suggest to do it after. BTW: you refer to an image but there is no image.

Comment: Thank you for the kind suggestion. Actually I have placed my HTML and javascript related to my current concern only. The image is just containing a very small cross button.

Comment: Thank you **Bas van Stein** for showing me the correct way.

You Rock!

Comment: You are welcome! You can post and accept it as answer yourself ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you add the click listener before or after you set the headerdiv html? If you do it before, I suggest to do it after. BTW: you refer to an image but there is no image. – **Bas van Stein** 17 hours ago

Thank you for solving my problem.

This is all I did

function bindCloseBlockUIpopup() 
{

```
/*Bind click functionality to close the pop up div starts*/

$('.closeme').click(function (e) {
    setTimeout($.unblockUI, 50);            
});

/*Bind click functionality to close the pop up div ends*/
```

}

function OpenBlockUIpopup()
{

```
try
{   

    $.blockUI(


         {
            message: $('#MyPopUpDiv'),
            theme: true,//Make the pop up draggable
            draggable: true,
            fadeIn: 300,
            fadeOut: 300,
            showOverlay: true,
            centerY: 0
         }
    );

    /* Get my previous header div's markup so that I can add my div to header provided by jquery ui */

    var appendHdrContent = $("#divHeaderWithCloseButton").html();


    /* Remove My previous header div from existing DOM */

    $("#divHeaderWithCloseButton").remove();


    /* Append my div into header provided by jquery */

    headerdiv.html(appendHdrContent);

    /*Enable popup to close on clicking cross button containing 'closeme' class*/

    bindCloseBlockUIpopup();
}
catch (e) 
{ 
    alert(e);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The click event on element with the class `closeme` is not fired, because the element is loaded after the document ready state.
In this case you should use the jquery's `delegate` function.
http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

```
$('.ui-widget-header').delegate( '.closeme', "click", function() {
  alert('Close button is clicked')
  // the code that actually closes the div here ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you for yours kind suggestion. It works and you Rock ;)